# Users can't add product to cart in Magento

Tags: magento

Magento 1.4.2
Uses remote database
Lightspeed Cache

When a user tries to add a product to the cart it doesn't add the product. The issue is reproducible if a product page is left for an hour and then you try to add the product to the cart.

I have synced the time on the database server and the Magento server.
I researched the issue on forums and have not found any solutions.
Tried adjusting the the cookie timeouts to no affect.

Clearing browser cache or clearing sessions in the var directory is a temp fix.

Has anyone encountered this issue? Does anyone have some suggestions what direction I should look into?

Comment: Is it an Ajax add-to-cart solution or standard POST? You say it doesn't add the product, but what does happen? Does it take you to an empty cart, or an error page? Or nothing at all?

Comment: Ajax Cart Pro by Ahead Works is installed (upgraded to the latest version today and the problem still exists). So the user doesn't leave the page they are on. The cart link at the top shows 1 item in the cart. When you go to the cart page there is nothing in the cart.

Comment: Install firebug for Firefox or just use Google Chrome. Have a look for javascript errors & use the Net/Network tabs to check the POST data being sent and the result returned.

Comment: Also, contact aheadWorks and ask them if they've encountered a similar problem. It may be an issue with their release.

Comment: You can also just disable the AheadWorks module via `app/etc/modules/` and see if its reproduced to help pinpoint the issue.

Comment: We already had AheadWorks look at our site and say that it has nothing to do with their module.

Comment: I have some experience with Lightspeed.  Make sure your `<lightspeed><session>` section is filled out correctly in `app/etc/local.xml`.  I have found TinyBrick/Ascendum's technical support to be very helpful in situations like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just need to go to `Admin >> System >> Configuration >> web >> Session Cookie Management` and change the value of cookie lifetime to 86400 and its done, hope it helps.

Comment: If you are using localhost, you can switch it into 127.0.0.1 as your local address and try.